# Customize Eclipse process console tool bar

Tags: eclipse

I want to rearrange the tool bar buttons for Eclipse console and remove some items. Is this possible? Customizing the main menu bar and tool bar for the entire application can be done easily.

I'd like access to both the View action and Context menu options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Console View does not permit this.

Comment: Oh... too bad. (Not sure why I got downvoted for the question, customization of this sort seems like it could be possible.)